# Adobe AIR Sqlite assync transactions

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, air

Here is the problem that I want to implement a solution, I have some data that needs to be writen in a database,data comes from network and it could arrive in "parallel", also for performance reasons the code is using async connection. The problem is that I have some bugs in my implementation ,I want to rewrite this code so it also uses transactions and rolloback,handle all possible errors and the code should be clean and easy to understand.
I am unable to find example code to read to get inspired or something to use directly, looking on what others done would help a lot.
So anyone know or has such example code? 
I think I need to write some code that will allow me to chain this methods :begin->execute->commit->end transaction and in case of errors rollback

Update

what I want to find or implement is something like

Update2 so where things get confusing is when you want to insert an array of stuff, you will need to use a loop and then use the execute method async, and then when it succeds insert the next element and so on, this makes it a little more complicated especialy if I want to abstract this ito have all this section of code in a single place and not all over my code.

```
function executeAssyncAsTransaction(statement:SqlStatement,responder:Responder):void{
    //step 1 begin transaction
    //step 2 execute
    //step 3 commit
    //step 4 end transaction
    //step 5 handle errors and rollback
    //use responders above no event listeners
}
```

I think I know how to implement this but I know that there is a chance I do it wrong (my current implementation that is in production crashes sometimes on some machines so I I know is hard to write 100% error free code)

I am, also thinking to implement a queue that will store my statements if needed(if database is busy) so I don't get an error and have to try again later

Comment: Which script language do you use? ActionScript or JavaScript?

Comment: @PaulFacklam my language is AS3 but JS examples that do what I need are good too because I am not interested in only copy paste solutions, reading good code is perfect.(I updated my post

Comment: You have to use event listeners to synchronize (chain) your async operations.

Comment: @PaulFacklam I can use Responders too, I am I wrong?

Comment: Ok. From the beginning. You have data that comes from a certain network (using the responder) and you want to write it into the database. Therefore you need to use async database operations in Adobe Air and something to synchronize them like event listeners. I think you can not use your responder object to synchronize db operations in Adobe Air. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @PaulFacklam if you check the API for SqlConnectiona and SqlStatement you will find that methods like execute, commit accept an optional parameter of type responder, if you use that you don't get the events, and I think I can create a responder to be passed trogh the chain, but events will work similar too with anonymus functions or similar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51663/discussion-between-simion314-and-paul-facklam)

Answer (score 1):

Use event listeners, error and callback functions in Adobe Air for JavaScript like this:

```
var conn = new air.SQLConnection(); 

conn.addEventListener(air.SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler); 
conn.addEventListener(air.SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler); 

// The database file is in the application storage directory 
var folder = air.File.applicationStorageDirectory; 
var dbFile = folder.resolvePath("DBSample.db"); 

conn.openAsync(dbFile); 

function openHandler(event) 
{ 
    air.trace("the database was created successfully"); 
} 

function errorHandler(event) 
{ 
    air.trace("Error message:", event.error.message); 
    air.trace("Details:", event.error.details); 
}
```

For ActionScript read these ressources:

http://de.slideshare.net/peterelst/introduction-to-sqlite-in-adobe-air-1627545